# In Laravel, defer database updates to end of week, and be able to view pending updates in browser

Tags: php, laravel, queue, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have a Laravel app where users can perform basic CRUD operations on data. However, the data must remain unchanged during the week. CRUD requests should be logged and executed in bulk at the end of each week.

The user story is that they are scheduling modifications for next week's data. They should be able to view the current week's data in its fixed state, knowing that it will remain constant for the entire week. Then, they can  separately view a timeline of pending changes which will are scheduled to take effect at the end of the current week.

In short: database modifications are deferred until the end of the week, but the user can view next week's pending modifications.

I'm using Laravel's `Job` classes to encapsulate and log the requests.

I considered using the Job class' `delay` method to delay the job's dispatch until the end of the week, but if the pending job is sitting in the queue the whole week, there's no information to provide to the user during the week.

The other option I came up with is to create a separate table representing the current week's pending database alterations. Jobs will dispatch immediately, upon request. However, the dispatch method will not modify the database itself, but will create a record in this new table. At the end of the week, all the database modifications sitting in this table will be executed in a scheduled task.

I don't like this approach because it feels redundant/messy. CRUD operations are neatly encapsulated as jobs, but that data is duplicated when stored on the pending modification table. Furthermore, the job itself can be dispatched at any point during the week, but has no intrinsic connection to the point in time at which the data itself is modified.

Maybe create two jobs for each CRUD operation, e.g. `CreatePerson` and `ScheduleCreatePerson`?

I feel like there's a cleaner way to do this that better leverages the existing job interface.

Comment: If you want to be able to review pending changes, then really you need those changes exposed in an accessible place such as a database table.  Potentially one table could hold all changes with new values held as json in one field.  You could still queue a job, referencing the row in this table to be processed.  One concern I have is making sure the jobs get executed in the correct order since with multiple workers jobs might be executed out of sequence.

Comment: @Snapey In this case, multiple workers refer to multiple processes running queue:work, yes? This app is fairly small and each job is not much more than a single DB query -- I don't expect to require more than one worker. Furthermore, would it be a bad idea in this case to bypass the queue altogether and dispatch jobs using dispatchSync?

Comment: you cannot defer sync jobs. what I would do instead is at an update_at column to the new table and then have a cron job that checks at fixed intervals if there are any rows to process